# Why does Linux have a C compiler by default?

Tags: linux, compiling, c

Why does a Linux distribution have gcc installed in advance? Is it because most of the applications in linux are written in C?

What would happen if the gcc directory is deleted?

Comment: "Linux" doesn't have `gcc` installed in advance. `gcc` is part of certain installation configurations of certain distributions. `gcc` and dozens of programs you never have heard of (and never used).

Comment: so can a linux distribution work perfectly without a c compiler?

Comment: In general, yes. There are (or were) closed source programs though which are very low level and thus need to adapt to the kernel version by compiling some glue code. I have experienced that with VMware. But if you don't need those then your installation should work without `gcc`.

Comment: It's generally not installed has been my observation. If you do an installation where the option is to "install everything" then of course it'll be installed. But when I do "server" installs of different distros, it's typically not there. Even "desktop" installs don't have in general. If you select "developer desktop" then you get it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Why does a Linux distribution have gcc installed in advance?

*A* Linux distribution is rather vague. Some install it, most offer to install it (possibly even if you select the defaults during installation). However not all distributions will install it and you usually have a choice.

> Is it because most of the applications in Linux are written in C?

No. A C-compiler (any C-compiler, [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) is just an example, it might just as well be [clang/lvm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), or something else) is just incredibly handy to have. And not just on a Linux system, but also on BSDs or windows installations.

> What would happen if the gcc directory is deleted?

Assuming their are no programs installed which depend on any part of GCC (or an a part of it, such as the pre-processor) then everything will continue to work just fine. You just can not compile any new C programs with that GCC version you just deleted. If it was the last C-compiler (you can have multiple compilers installed) then you will need to use a binary package to reinstall it if you to compile any C programs later.

<sup>Note that with *What would happen if the gcc directory is deleted?* I assume you would delete it using the proper package manager. Just randomly deleting directories on any OS is not a safe thing to do.</sup>

Comment: Also, as far as I remember, POSIX requires a working C compiler to be available in a POSIX-compliant system. So, if a distribution wants to be as close as possible to POSIX, it needs a C compiler.

Comment: And many programs are distributed only in source form or for different platforms, with the user expected to compile them to work on their particular system. Not "most", but still a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't say that a C compiler comes in handy on Windows. Programs are usually distributed as installers or precompiled binaries, the user is not supposed to compile anything. On Unix this is completely different, of course.

Comment: @liori AFAIR, a C compiler is part of the (C) development option in all versions of POSIX. You don't need one to claim POSIX conformance, only to claim conformance with that option.

Comment: `dkms` requires `gcc` and you need `dkms`if you have external kernel modules (VirtualBox, virus scanner, specific hardware...) so they can be recompiled to work with your kernel updates.

Answer (score 3):

A number of utilities on Linux have been compiled using `gcc`.  Most of those utilities make calls to run-time shared library and in case you uninstall the total package, you will still need to keep the shared libraries.

I did a little search on `/bin/ls` using the command `strings -a /bin/ls` and it shows the use of libc.so which is the standard C library on Linux.  Since Linux is officially Gnu/Linux, I can assume that most of the utilities have been compiled with Gnu/C or gcc.  If you do `man libc`, you will notice that it indicates the use of glibc for most of the Linux utilities.  Hence, you need to keep `libc` and `glibc` for the utilities to work.

Comment: This answer would IMO be greatly improved by listing a few examples of applications which make such calls to GCC and its related toolchain and libraries after the applications have been built. Other than closed-source applications needing glue code to be updated e.g. when installing a new kernel version as mentioned by Hauke in the comments to the question, I can't think of any use case for that not related to software development (in which case you'd almost certainly want a compiler anyway, though of course it wouldn't necessarily have to be GCC in particular).

Comment: The shared library is `libgcc_s`, which is typically provided separately from gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of ABI compatibility especially in the past means that building from source is pretty common. Of course, many need more than just a C compiler to build too...

Answer (score 0):

On name-brand servers (HP Enterprises Proliant, Fujitsu Primergy, and others) the vendor-specific hardware monitoring drivers will often come in a form that includes some source code for the essential kernel interface components. The driver packages will usually also include pre-compiled drivers for any supported kernel versions known to the hardware vendor at the time the driver package was released.

That way, whenever a Linux distribution publishes a kernel security update, the hardware monitoring modules can be recompiled to match the updated kernel, without the need to wait for the hardware vendor to test and publish new packages to match the updated kernel.

Usually the monitoring drivers include some script automation that will automatically recompile the appropriate modules the first time the system is booted with a new kernel version. Of course this will be successful only if the compiler and the necessary kernel development/header package are installed on the system.

If this wasn't done, there might be times where installing a critical security upgrade would cost you much of your basic hardware monitoring information: the status of system PSUs, temperatures, fans and on modern servers usually power consumption too.

In datacenters, such monitoring can make the difference between "Oh, a redundant fan/PSU has died, I'll send the datacenter guy to hot-swap it during office hours tomorrow" and "The server had lost too many fans, started to overheat and shut itself down. Now a SLA is broken and the customer is unhappy - the server needs to be fixed or replaced ASAP at oh-dark-thirty." (Yes, not *everything* is cloud-based or even virtualized yet.)